# Why my print current date time (C language) gives different answer

Tags: c, datetime, printf

I want to get the current date (day, mon and year). I found out there are some functions in C to do that like ctime (get the string of time), localtime and gmtime. I tried with following code but the output are different. I get this output:

The date and time is Tue Apr 20 2010 (which is correct)

The year is : 110

The year is : 110.

Does anybody know why?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
   time_t now;
   if((now = time(NULL)) == (time_t)-1)
   {
      puts("Failure in getting time");
   }
   else {
      printf("The date and time is: %s\n", ctime(&now));
      printf("The year is: %ld\n", localtime(&now)->tm_year);
      printf("The year is: %ld\n", gmtime(&now)->tm_year);
   }
   getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the man page for ctiime - the year field is years from 1900.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime

```
tm_year
The number of years since 1900.
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I did it wrongly for both mon and year in my program

Comment: @vodkhang, a lot of people make that mistake.  That's why the first line of defence is to read the man page.